# About Updation of contract

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, multi-index

I have 2 questions about updation of contract and multi-indexed tables?

1)Can i update contract as if i want to change ram payer for multi indexed 
  tables can i change it after deploying contract ? will it affect to my 
  multi-indexed tables as i mean will it work as it was working before ?

2)Can I update my table structure (add more fields to table or remove any 
  fields) after deployment of contract ?

Comment: you can update the payer for entries, but you cannot change the structure without basically migrating all the data

Comment: and is there any way to migrating data automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can update your contract to change who will pay for RAM in tables, but it will only affect the RAM-payer going forwards from this point in time. Whoever paid for RAM until now will continue paying for RAM until the entry is updated or destroyed.
2. You can update your table structure, but ONLY if you have no entries in your table. If you already have entries in your table, then you will have to create a new table with a different name, and use a function to transfer each of your table entries from the old table to the new table.